# How to access the documents in using javascript in SharePoint 2013 Preview?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, 2013

I try to get familiar with with the Javascript API of SharePoint 2013 (Preview). Therefore I started a SharePoint-hosted app using VS2012. The default app works just great after deploying to my local SharePoint 2013.

Now I try to get access to the documents of that SharePoint instance using Javascript but I couldn't find an point to get started for this in the API documentation. Any hint what namespace / functions / etc. use to get access to documents would be great.

For example: "How many documents are in the library or a given view etc.?"

Thx, Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you would want to do is have a look at the JavaScript Client Object Model (2013). It has all the classes for the functionality you want to achieve.

A great link to start with it is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx

And here is a complete reference of the JavaScript API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246996(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I found that already. Its about website properties, list and listitems. I am looking for accessing the document-library but can't find that stuff in any reference. Maybe I am looking for the wrong keywords. Are documents stored in list-items or is this something different?

Comment: Yes documents are indeed stored as list items. You will have to use SP.ListItem.get_file(); to get the file properties of the document. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552478
This link is of the SP2010 Client Object Model but it should work in the 2013 version too.

Comment: ah ok. that makes sense now. thx!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using CSOM from JavaScript you may find it a lot easier to use the [REST api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

To get information about a document library you may use:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')`

To only get the number of documents use:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')?$select=ItemCount`

To get list of items to see properties use:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items`

To get file info about a single item use:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items(1)/File`

Amongst the properties is the ServerRelativeUrl you can use to get the file.

To work through folder you can use:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder`

And continue down through:
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder/Files`
or
`http://sp2013srv/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder/Folders`

Comment: The REST API is indeed great but I feel it is more useful if you are programming on a non-windows platform. Also, batch processing and the ability to program against objects make me lean more on the side of the JSCOM. I would suggest @Marc to have a look at the following link to determine what API is right for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060(v=office.15)#RESTOData

Comment: Are files/documents (Default Installation > Menu > "Documents") stored in list-items so I need to use the list's API?

Comment: I see an advantage for the REST API on Windows-Platforms too: I'd like to use ASP.Net MVC for my provider-hosted app. Have to try that but maybe REST is an easy alternative to .Net library which is not by default supported in MVC.