# Download bulk data of around 150gb from Sharepoint 2013

Tags: document, libraries, download

I am using sharepoint 2013 which has document libraries consists of around 150gb data which i need to download it to my hard drive..one of the method that i came across is.

open with explorer

are there any other methods?

Comment: How open are you to using PowerShell / C#?

Comment: i have powershell script but downloading 150gb data doesnt seems to be feasible option as we need to consider type of files, connection, sessions problem etc. if u have any c# code , then it would be helpful

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44724/how-to-access-the-documents-in-using-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013-preview ?

Comment: yes..bt nt able to understand it :P..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the REST service, but since you are downloading this amount of data you could as well use the CSOM.
Try this:

Install the **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client** package from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
```

(This package is for 2010, but it will work for 2013 as well).
Then use this code:

```
const string host = "http://2013-sp";
const string documentLibTitle = "Documents";
const string savePath = @"C:\Temp";
using (var ctx = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(host))
{
    var items = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibTitle).GetItems(new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery());
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(items).ForEach(item => 
    {
        var path = "" + item["FileRef"];
        var name = "" + item["FileLeafRef"];
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(savePath, name)))
        {
            var file = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, path);
            file.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    });
}
```

If you need to authenticate with username/password do this:

```
using (var ctx = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(host)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "DOMAIN")
})
{
```

Note that the file here is a stream, so you can write out the progress if you like.

Comment: this is faster or with powershell?

Comment: I think that depends if you are sitting on the server or not, with PowerShell you might want to use remote powershell, and then it will probably have the same speed, but without the ability to print information about progress pr. file.